# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease' - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have successfully created an android application using android studio, and works fine when i run into android emulator or device connected to the development machine, but when i try to install the apk from build/outputs/apk the application crashes on opening.Also i tried to generate signed apk from android studio from build -> Generate signed apk (both release and debug) but it fails to generate the apk with the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Identifier;
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aitrich.android.modern.photo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.0.1'
    playServicesVersion = '9.0.2'
    retrofitVersion = '2.1.0'
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
}

apt {
    arguments {
        stagGeneratedPackageName "com.aitrich.android.modern.stag.generated"
        stagDebug true
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.vimeo.stag:stag-library:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:1.0.6'
    compile 'ch.halcyon:squareprogressbar:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0-native'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.8'
    compile('com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile('com.github.StevenDXC:DxLoadingButton:1.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile('com.redmadrobot:chronos:1.0.7') {
        exclude module: 'eventbus:2.4.0'
    }
    compile ('co.infinum:materialdatetimepicker-support:3.1.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.vimeo.stag:stag-library-compiler:2.0.2'
    apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Please check you having this two libraries common :

```
 compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
 compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0-native'
```

remove one of them and check which one is needed for you.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38051280/3960700) answer for multidex issue.that one helped me to fix that issue.

It seems your logcat clearly shows annotations identifier `DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Identifier`. You should [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26713987/3960700) this line support -annotations:

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

Moreover, If you are using google play services bundle like this : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0`

change into below gms separately for all libraries

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'

 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'    //
```

for gcm push notification

Comment: Thank u for ur quick response, but unfortunately i am not using any if the above mentioned dependencies in my project.

Comment: @darwin where is dex options and packaging options in that edited post gradle file

Comment: sorry i forgot it, but still smae issue after adding     dexOptions {
        //incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
    }

Comment: @darwin inside the application element in manifest you added this line?  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: still same issue

Comment: @darwin can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26713987/3960700)

Comment: sure, i will check and inform u asap

Comment: i dont know how to remove android-support-v4.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140167/discussion-between-stephen-and-darwin).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling multidex . inside app level **build.gradle** write these lines

```
   android {
...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
       ...
   }

...
}
dependencies {
...
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
...
}
```

check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for more info

Comment: i will post my gradle file,pls check updated question